# How can i display sentence mix of two font face in text view in android?

Tags: android, string, utf-8, character-encoding, textview

I am new in android can any one help me to solve this ?

My question is i have UTF-8 encoding stored in the MySQL table, It comprises of english and other language i,e Rich Text Format like ***કેમ છો Brother ?***

I want to display this in android textview or readonly edittext but not in webview.

Is there anyone who can help me ?

I can store two types of fonts in assets but i guess we can apply only one at a time.

Comment: Why changing fonts, when you can use one font with both English and Gujarati glyphs?

Answer (score 1):

this may help you

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("< font>"+ur first font here+"< / font >< font >"+your second font hrer +"< / font >"));
```

Comment: How does this help? I'm facing the same problem and so far only the face attribute is working - but only with default defined fonts...